# Como manipular um link no href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache-cordova

É possível eu tratar um **link**, por exemplo quando eu clicar e a página não existir, eu redirecionar para algum lugar especifico?

Por uma página de "ops este link não existe" por exemplo.

Pois no meu caso estou fazendo um appWeb (phonegap), onde eu queria redirecionar o app para outro app, caso o mesmo não existir redirecionar para a loja.

Comment: É possivel testando com ajax, mas com algumas reservas. Essa outra página é do mesmo dominio?

Comment: Sim seria dentro do mesmo dominio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso com AJAX. Crias uma chamada ajax para esse url e consoante a resposta sabes se o url existe, tem erros ou não. Um exemplo seria assim:

```
function verificar(url, cb) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) cb(true);
        else cb(false);
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
        cb(false);
    };
    request.send();
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', verificador(links[i]))
}

function verificador(el) {
    return function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = e.target.href;
        var status = verificar(url, function(sucesso){
                alert('Essa página ' + (sucesso ? 'existe!' : 'não existe :('));
        });
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/djsjx70z/

Comment: foi de grande valia este código, agradeço a atenção.